# How to perform coreference Resolution in Java using Stanford core NLP?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, stanford-nlp

I have a paragraph of text, and I want to perform coref resolution on it, so that all pronouns in it will be replaced by nouns. Here's the code I'm using:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref");
StanfordCoreNLP pi= new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

String text = "Delhi is the capital city of India.It is the second most populous metropolis in India after Mumbai and the largest city in terms of area.";   
Annotation doc = new Annotation(text);
pi.annotate(doc);
Map<Integer, CorefChain> graph = doc.get(CorefChainAnnotation.class);
for (Map.Entry entry : graph.entrySet()) { 
    CorefChain c = (CorefChain) entry.getValue();
    CorefMention cm = c.getRepresentativeMention();
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error? Take a look at this example code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688739/resolve-coreference-using-stanford-corenlp-unable-to-load-parser-model It worked for me as well as the example code in the downloaded package (/stanfordNLP/StanfordCoreNlpDemo.java)

Comment: ant see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572207/stanford-core-nlp-understanding-coreference-resolution